# Bezout Coefficient for polynomials in sage?

Tags: divisibility, arithmetic-functions, sagemath

I want to find the bezout coefficient for those 2 polynomials :

$f = 1+x-x^2-x^4+x^5$ and $g = -1+x^2+x^3-x^6$
when I use the gcd function in sage the output is :

```
sage: gcd(f,g)
sage: 1
```

but when I use xgcd(f,g) it gives me the following :

($-27$, $9*x^5 - 18*x^2 - 9*x - 9$, $9*x^4 - 9*x^3 - 18*x + 18$)

I want xgcd to give me 1 instead of -27 so the polynomials will be the bezout coefficients

P.S: I can't divide the polynomials by -27 because i'm working in ZZ

Comment: I suppose the gcd is computed over the rationals.

Comment: I suspect that you will find https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sage-devel/JV8fCPUqTzo/overview quite relevant here.

Comment: See also http://ask.sagemath.org/question/26954/bezout-coefficients/

Comment: Thank you so much, 111 you were right I should work with rational polynomials